# list of browsers that support direct write widows7

Tags: list, firefox, browser, windows-7

Does firefox 3.5 and firefox 3.6 support direct write.Moreover can anyone provide me the list of browser which support direct write technology in windows7.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, IE9+ and Firefox 4+.  That's it.